# How can i call Java web service method in blackberry web works/HTML5 app?

Tags: java, javascript, css, html, blackberry

I am developing blackberry web works/HTML5 application for blackberry OS 7 environment and testing it with ripple emulator.
I have developed java web service which retrieves data from database and returns it to calling client.

How can i invoke web service in HTML5 code? and How can i check whether web service call will be successful or not in ripple emulator?

Comment: Same as in every other web page: making HTTP calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a pretty good example on the blackberry forums here: [Blackberry Forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Calling-a-web-service-from-a-BlackBerry-WebWorks-Application/ta-p/555555)

You just need to create a new XMLHttpRequest, oopen it, and send the request. Also create a callback function to handle the result. Example below:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
function CallWebService(){
    xmlHttp.open('GET', 'http://YOURWEBSERVICEURLHERE', true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;
    xmlHttp.send();
}

function callbackFunction(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState != 4) 
    return; 
var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
alert(result);  
}
```

Comment: Mooring : Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Uday you're welcome. Please mark my response as the answer so the thread can close.